# Solving Linear System of Equation in Polynomial Time

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

Let $ \mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}_+^n$, $\mathbf{E}  \in \mathbb{R}_+^{n \times m}$, $\mathbf{V}  \in \mathbb{R}_+^{n \times m}$ with $\mathbf{E}^T \mathbf{1}_n = \mathbf{1}_m$ and $\mathbf{V} \mathbf{1}_m = \mathbf{1}_n$, and $\forall i, j \ \ E_{ij} \geq 0, \ \ V_{ij} \geq 0$ where $\mathbf{1}_n$ is the vector of ones of size $n$.

I have the following system of equations where I am trying to find a closed form solution for non-negative $\mathbf{p}$ (i.e., $\mathbf{p} \in \mathbb{R}_+^m$):
\begin{align}
\mathbf{1}_m = \mathbf{V}^T D^{-1}(\mathbf{V} \mathbf{p}) \mathbf{E} \mathbf{p}
\end{align}
where $D(\mathbf{x})$ is the diagonal matrix whose $(i, i)^{th}$ entry corresponds to $x_i$ and $D^{-1}(\mathbf{x})$ is the inverse of $D(\mathbf{x})$.

Is it possible to solve for  non-negative $\mathbf{p}$ (i.e., $\mathbf{p} \in \mathbb{R}_+^m$) in polynomial time? What would be such an algorithm? Otherwise, can I find an approximation in polynomial time?

Comment: Your notation isn't consistent in that $Vp$ is an $n$ by $1$ column vector and $E$ is an $n$ by $m$ vector.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, $D(\mathbf{x})$ is the diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are those of $\mathbf{x}$. I edited the text for clarity. I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: It's still the case that $(Vp)Ep$ isn't properly conforming matrix multiplication.

Comment: $D^{-1}(\mathbf{V}\mathbf{p})$ is a diagonal matrix of size $n \times n$. In particular it is the inverse of the diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries correspond to $\mathbf{V}\mathbf{p}$. Is there a better way for me to express this?

Comment: It would be clearer if you wrote this as $\mbox{diag}(Vp)^{-1}$.  It's clear enough now.

Comment: The variable to solve $p$  is in the numerator and denominator like this problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3739904/recovering-three-dimensional-vectors-after-projection-and-cross-product

Comment: Thanks, this might be a great starting point for me!