# Solving for vector $\vec{r}$

Tags: vectors

Solve for **r** if  **r** $×$ **b = a** $\space$ and given **a** and **b** are perpendicular.

**My attempt:** I already have a method i.e let **r = $x$a + $y$b + $z$(a × b)** substituting in given equation  and  comparing the coefficients using the fact that **a, b ,a × b**  are non planar  **r** can be found. But is there a better method to solve this problem. A hint will suffice.

Comment: The fact that $\mathrm r \times \mathrm b = \mathrm a$ tells us that either $\mathrm a$ and $\mathrm b$ are perpendicular or $\mathrm a = 0.$

Comment: In fact, $a$, $b$, $a\times b$ form an orthogonal basis, so there is only one non-zero coefficient to compare.

Comment: Are you sure the condition is not supposed to be "$\mathrm r$ and $\mathrm b$ are perpendicular"?

Comment: By the way, when you write an equation, put the whole thing in MathJax, not just individual variables (like `$x$`). I'm surprised someone bothered to edit this question without fixing that.

Answer (score 2):

i think this is a duplicate : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/32602/427318 seems to give an answer. to explain, if r is perpendicular to b, then it's fairly easy to find the inverse, but any component parallel to b will just disappear due to the bilinearity of the cross product, so there may be an arbitrary nonzero b component (no "a" as it must be perpendicular to both r and b, or 0)

splitting up r into the two components- one parallel to b, and one perpendicular to both a, and b, e.g of the form r= t(bxa)+s(b) and then using the vector triple product identity
$\mathbf{a}\times (\mathbf{b}\times \mathbf{c}) = (\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{c})\mathbf{b} -(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}) \mathbf{c}$  + anticommutativity of the cross product to find t should give the answer relatively simply, as most of the terms in the triple product will be zero by orthogonality, thus no need for coefficients