# Determining value of unit vector that satisfies cross product equation

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

Consider the equation given by: $\langle 0,-1, 0 \rangle$ = $-qV \times \langle -1,0,0 \rangle$, where $\times$ denotes the cross product. I have to find a suitable standard basis vector $V$ that satisfies this equation. Where I'm getting stuck is since $\langle 0,-1, 0 \rangle$ is orthogonal to $-qV$ and $\langle -1,0,0 \rangle$, then I can express $-qV$ as $\langle 0,-1,0 \rangle \times \langle -1,0,0 \rangle$, which gives $-qV$ = $\langle 0,0,-1 \rangle$ and hence $V = \langle 0,0,1/q \rangle$. However, the answer to this problem is $V = \langle 0,0,-1/q \rangle$. I'm not sure where I am going wrong, but it seems I am off by a factor of negative $1$.

I am utilizing the result found in this link [Opposite of a cross product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32600/whats-the-opposite-of-a-cross-product)

If anyone could find my algebra mistake, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the negative sign, $\langle 0 ,-1, 0\rangle \times \langle -1, 0, 0 \rangle = \langle0, 0, 1\rangle$ i.e $-j \times -i = k$. So $v = \frac {-1}{q} k$

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%3C0%2C+-1%2C0%3E+x+%3C-1%2C0%2C0%3E

Comment: According to Wolfram, <0,-1,0> x <-1,0,0> = <0,0,-1> though?

Comment: wolfram is also right. Observe how it measures the vectors. it follows $j \times i = k$, $i \times k = j$  and $k \times j = i$.

Comment: If Wolfram is right, then your explanation isn't. But I think I figured out where I dropped the negative. You have to cross <0,-1,0> x - <-1,0,0> = <0,-1,0> x <1,0,0> instead

Comment: The usual way is that $i \times j = k$. In wolfram, The polarity of the unit vectors are reversed.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my answer, I dropped the negative when crossing <0,-1,0> with - <-1,0,0>.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, consider  $ c = a \times b$. Then if $c$ is orthogonal to $a$ and $b$, the solutions are given by $ b = (c \times a)/(a\, . a) + t a$ for arbitrary scalars $t$, and $a = (c \times -b)/(b\, . b) + t b$ for arbitrary scalars $t$. In the problem above, we can take $c = <0,-1,0>, a = -qV, b = <-1,0,0>.$ Solving for $a$ gives $a = <0,-1,0> x$ $- <-1,0,0>$, hence I dropped the negative here.

The answer posted on the hyperlink above was incomplete.